# How to create a draggable carousal slide with an unordered list inside the slides?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I require some assistance in creating a unordered list (with dropdowns) inside a draggable carousal slide.

You will see that I am unable to access the dropdown menu when clicking on the list item. What could I do to resolve the below issue?

[image: Sample Photo]

You will see that I was able to create the unordered list inside the carousal, however, I am just experiencing display issues.

**Sample Code:** [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/WimpieN/qp57kvdc/2/).

```js
const carousel = document.querySelector('.carousel');
const slidesContainer = carousel.querySelector('.carousel-container');
const slides = Array.from(carousel.querySelectorAll('.carousel-slide'));
const arrowLeft = carousel.querySelector('.carousel-arrow.left');
const arrowRight = carousel.querySelector('.carousel-arrow.right');
let currentIndex = 0;
let isDragging = false;
let startPos = 0;
let currentTranslate = 0;
let prevTranslate = 0;

function handleDragStart(event) {
  isDragging = true;
  startPos = getPositionX(event);
  prevTranslate = currentTranslate;
  slidesContainer.style.transition = 'none';
}

function handleDragMove(event) {
  if (!isDragging) return;
  const currentPosition = getPositionX(event);
  currentTranslate = prevTranslate + currentPosition - startPos;
  setSliderPosition();
}

function handleDragEnd() {
  isDragging = false;
  const slideWidth = slides[0].offsetWidth;
  if (currentTranslate < -slideWidth / 4) {
    currentIndex += 1;
  } else if (currentTranslate > slideWidth / 4) {
    currentIndex -= 1;
  }
  slidesContainer.style.transition = 'transform 0.4s ease-in-out';
  setSliderPosition();
}

function setSliderPosition() {
  slidesContainer.style.transform = `translateX(${currentTranslate}px)`;
}

function getPositionX(event) {
  return event.type.includes('mouse') ? event.pageX : event.touches[0].clientX;
}

function showSlide(index) {
  currentIndex = index;
  currentTranslate = -slides[currentIndex].offsetLeft;
  slidesContainer.style.transform = `translateX(${currentTranslate}px)`;
}

function slideToNext() {
  if (currentIndex === slides.length - 1) {
    currentIndex = 0;
  } else {
    currentIndex += 1;
  }
  showSlide(currentIndex);
}

function slideToPrev() {
  if (currentIndex === 0) {
    currentIndex = slides.length - 1;
  } else {
    currentIndex -= 1;
  }
  showSlide(currentIndex);
}

arrowLeft.addEventListener('click', slideToPrev);
arrowRight.addEventListener('click', slideToNext);

slidesContainer.addEventListener('mousedown', handleDragStart);
slidesContainer.addEventListener('touchstart', handleDragStart);
slidesContainer.addEventListener('mousemove', handleDragMove);
slidesContainer.addEventListener('touchmove', handleDragMove);
slidesContainer.addEventListener('mouseup', handleDragEnd);
slidesContainer.addEventListener('touchend', handleDragEnd);
slidesContainer.addEventListener('mouseleave', handleDragEnd);
```

```css
.carousel {
  width: 600px;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.carousel-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.carousel-slide {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.carousel-slide img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.carousel-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.carousel-arrow.left {
  left: 10px;
}

.carousel-arrow.right {
  right: 10px;
}

.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav-list li {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-container">
      <div class="carousel-slide">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="Slide 1">
        <ul class="nav nav-list">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown1" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown 1
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown1">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown Item 1</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown Item 2</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown Item 3</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown 2
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown2">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown Item 1</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown Item 2</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown Item 3</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-slide">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="Slide 2">
        <ul class="nav nav-list">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown3" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown 1
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown3">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown Item 1</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown Item 2</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown Item 3</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown4" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown 2
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown4">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown Item 1</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown Item 2</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown Item 3</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-slide">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="Slide 3">
        <ul class="nav nav-list">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown5" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown 1
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown5">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown Item 1</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown Item 2</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown Item 3</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown6" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown 2
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown6">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown Item 1</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown Item 2</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown Item 3</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-arrow left">&lt;</div>
    <div class="carousel-arrow right">&gt;</div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Protip: You can include more than one event type in an event listener, as `.addEventListener('mousedown touchstart', ...`. This allows you to reduce the number of such statements in your code by half in this case.

Comment: Protip: Bootstap version 4.0.0 is very old. You should be able to update to 4.6.x without issue.

Comment: The primary issue is that you have overflow hidden on your carousel element. I'm not sure why you have so much custom CSS for this. Maybe try starting with [Bootstrap's carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/carousel/) and make small modifications as needed to achieve your other goals.

Comment: @isherwood - I have tried only using Bootstrap, but I was unsuccessful. I am not certain what I am missing, but I keep breaking the carousel.